# Is it possible to add the Gutenberg block editor to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, block-editor

I have been trying to find a way to do it but I can't get it to work. I have tried `show_in_rest => 'true'` which works for custom post types but not custom taxonomies. I also found an example on here to add this to my functions file but it didn't work either.

```
function ux_portfolio_block_cat_editor( $args, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'my_taxonomy_name_here' === $taxonomy ) {
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'ux_portfolio_block_cat_editor', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: If you mean to have the editor on the taxonomy/term edit pages, then no, I don't think it's possible. But the editor uses the REST API, hence for the editor to be able to read/write/delete post data, post types need to be enabled in the REST API, so that's why `'show_in_rest' => true` is needed for post types with the block editor support.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant. Wanting to have the editor on the taxonomy/category edit pages instead of the classic editor.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to stick to the classic editor for now..

Comment: Pity. Thank you for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But you actually have to create your custom taxonomy in a slightly different way. Try this:

```
add_action('init', function () {
    $args = array(
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => [ 'slug' => 'my_taxonomy_name_here' ],
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'my_taxonomy_name_here', [ 'post' ], $args );

    
    // Optional - create the custom post type
    $args = array(
        'description'       => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
        'public'            => true,
        'menu_position'     => 5,
        'taxonomies' => array('my_taxonomy_name_here'),
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
        'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'taxonomies' ),
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
    );
    register_post_type('YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', $args);
});
```

This will create custom post type, using Gutenberg, and even include your custom taxonomies.